# Why does Anise's HP keep rising?

Tags: tales-of-the-abyss

At the end of almost 1/2 my battles with Anise after i defeated the Blade Dancer on Coral Castle, a message comes up saying her Max HP has increased however this happens regardless if she leveled up.

I am wondering how this is happening as i have recived no other message like it for any other character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an AD Skill that sometimes grants HP after a battle. See [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/609541-/61892007).